# how to output it in php?

Tags: php, xml

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object
 (
    [@attributes] => Array
    (
        [version] => 2.0
    )

   [channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [title] => idcspy
        [link] => http://idcspy.com
        [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [language] => zh-hans
        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [title] => hello world.
                        [link] => http://example.com/node/48
                        [description] => ....
```

now, i want to echo the hello world and the link value. how to output it.when i used this :`echo $doc->channel->item[0]['title'];` there is no any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $doc->channel->item[0]->title;
```

Comment: enjoylife, the reason why this requires the object accessor (->) rather than a direct array accessor because if you look at what each type is, you can see [0] is defined as another SimpleXMLElement Object, while [item] is defined as an array.

Comment: if there are lots of title. how to loop them then output them.

Comment: foreach ($doc->channel->item as $item) echo $item->title;

Comment: if i only want to output 10 result. how should i do?

Comment: use for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) echo $doc->channel->item[$i]->title;

Comment: what's the difference between the for loop and foreach loop? the foreach loops over the whole loop. the for loop which you can specify how many steps you will be loop. am i right,?

Comment: for-loop more common, you can use different statements as condition/init/loop-statement. foreach works only with arrays. But in this case you are right.

Comment: now, i want to ouptput two variable's value at the same time. title and link, i do like this, for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){ $title=$doc->channel->item[$i]->title;
        $link=$doc->channel->item[$i]->link; echo $title.$link;} is there a better way to do this?